# attach a database to Azure data studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, macos, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am running Azura data studio on docker on my Mac, and have a server running, in which I need to attach a database to that I have locally in .mdf format. I have tried right clicking to click attach database as you would in sql server express, but it isn't working, nothing shows up when I right click but `refresh`.

I have also tried running this SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE myDB ON 
(FILENAME = './databasesLocal/mydb.mdf'),
(FILENAME = './databasesLocal/mydb.ldf') 
FOR ATTACH;
```

but when I do this, I get this error:

> Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>  A file activation error
> occurred. The physical file name './databasesLocal/mydb.mdf' may be
> incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the
> operation.

does anyone know what I can do to attach a database?

Comment: Where did you place the database files in the container?

Comment: well it's stored on my Mac locally, no where in the container rn. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: So does the container have access to that location? You can't attach a database that the environment the instance is running on has no access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to attach database with below code:

```
CREATE  DATABASE  myDB1
ON (FILENAME  =  '.DATA\db.mdf'),
(FILENAME  =  '.DATA\db.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

I got below error:

[image]

I tried with below code:

```
 CREATE  DATABASE  myDB1
    ON (FILENAME  =  'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME  =  'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\db.ldf')
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Command run successfully

[image]

Database created successfully.

[image]

Once check your file path properly. Give the whole path file. Even if you have whitespace in path, you will get the error. Along with that check your folder permission.